# Character can rotate a ring or circle off of any point, how deadly is this power?

Tags: super-powers

I made a character that can rotate rings or circles off any point they can see, and now I'm wondering how deadly this is, and if it's practical in gunfights and such. Here's the details on it-

The diameter of the rings/circles is up to a hundred feet. If it is a ring(center is not rotating), the ring could be anywhere between a few inches and 50 feet wide. the rings/circles can be rotated at any speed up to mach 1(might change if it's too powerful). Rings/circles affect all matter up to ten feet above the plane of movement(but can be lower if Bob wants). People in the ring feel no acceleration or movement, but looking out of the rotating area is really trippy and confusing. Any matter that is suddenly hovering in the air does not fall until the ring/circle is dispelled. Bob has tuned his powers so he has lots of control. If standing below you, he can rotate your legs to the side and cut you in half. Bob is subject to the rings/circles like anyone else. All matter in the ring/circle rotates. Any matter entering the ring/circle begins to rotate with it until the ring stops(putting your hand in the ring will get your hand chopped off). Entering and exiting the ring/circle while it is spinning is very risky and most of the time causes injury or death. The plane of movement can be at any angle, and people affected feel gravity become the plane of movement(Bob can walk up walls if done right). Bob can only do one ring/circle at a time, and the concentration required keeps him from doing much else. There is no reload time needed between creating rings. Bob is human. The rotation point for the ring/circle can be anywhere Bob can see and within a half mile. Bob can move rings without needing to wave his hands around, but it helps.

If I have forgotten anything or add some for any reason, they'll be put below.

- thought I already had this, but Bob affects matter above the ring/circle(in relation to the plane of rotation) up to ten feet, but he can make it less if he wants to.

How deadly is this power? Would Bob stand a chance against a dozen bad guys with guns? Should Bob [be locked away forever](http://www.scpwiki.com/)?

Comment: i dont think you could lock him up, if he can rotate (spheres?) of anything he sees he could kill anyone in his sight, if they dont kill him first

Comment: You've already specified that Bob's power can kill, so clearly the power is deadly. I'm not seeing much of a question here - Bob can certainly kill anyone/everyone nearby enough, and whether he should be locked up or not depends entirely on what he actually does with his power.

Comment: By "rotating the ring", do you mean Bob's power works like the combat system in Paper Mario: The Origami King?

Comment: @IshaanSaha, im unfamiliar with that reference, but a quick search looks like yes it does look like what Bob can do

Comment: Those "circles" are actually supposed to be "disks", correct? (A circle consists of the points at a given distance $r$ called the radius from a given point $O$ called the center; if you want all the points with a distance not greater than $r$ that is called a [*disk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)). That is to say, a disk is the region of a plane bounded by a circle.)

Comment: @AlexP, if you want to get all technical, then yeah i guess so.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b instead of a disk, is it more like a cylinder? is there a height restriction to how much he can spin at one time?

Comment: @ITAlex, the height max is 10 feet above the plane of rotation, but it can be lowered if desired

Comment: When you say ring and circle, do you men torus and sphere?

Comment: One Bad Guy with a gun would suffice, wouldn't he? Bob never knew what hit him ...

Comment: @Daniel, I want the effect area to have hard edges so its easier to estimate where not to stand, so no i dont mean torus and sphere.

Comment: but a disc and circle is two dimensional, means infinitely thin, so Bob would not actually affect anything!

Comment: @Daniel, but the height of the ring/circle can be up to ten feet off the plane of rotation. I couldve sworn i put it in the question, but i guess ill add it now.

Comment: That would make it a cylinder, wouldn't it?

Comment: I really, really fail to see how the link has anything to do with the qiestion.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, it probably doesnt have anything to do with it, its just interesting :)

Comment: How fast is Bob's reaction time? What is the acceleration factor of the spinning disk/cylinder?

Comment: "Any matter that is suddenly hovering in the air does not fall until the ring/circle is dispelled." How long can he hold a ring stationary for, before it is 'dispelled'? Can he rotate a cylinder of earth 90 degrees, and keep it in that position for a prolonged period, as a shield? Seems to me he does not need to see his enemy, he just needs to know his enemy COULD be there, and then defend against any enemy action by raising (rotating) a pre-emptive shield.

Answer (score 7):

#### He will *literally* bury them alive.

[image]

This is a 50ft circle. The circle has diameter 12m, and half circumfrence of 38m. Mach 1 is 340m/s. The flip occurs in 112ms. Human reaction time is ~250ms.

The 12 guys wont get a shot off before they are completely inverted. Then they fall onto their heads, and are then buried by 25ft of earth.

Side View:
[image]

Comment: It will also copletely deafen them into shock, as the sudden acceleraion to mach 1 will create a shock wave that would do justice to Mythbusters.

Comment: "Spinning Wheel" What goes up, must come down; Spinning wheel got to go round; Blood, Sweat & Tears https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bloodsweattears/spinningwheel.html

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond this does raise an interesting point - after a while you'll be digging up old victims. Sure the poor fella has two 7.6m drops behind them (and one case of having a 7.6m layer of dirt being dropped onto), but I do suppose a sufficiently determined person with a gun can still shoot.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, this power is very deadly. Bob can destroy and kill anything at will within the specified half-mile range.
2. Whether Bob will prevail against a dozen opponents armed with firearms, it depends:

- If Bob and opponents are in a Western-style duel (and opponents are clustered), Bob is at a big advantage;
- If opponents are spread out, and Bob has no cover, Bob is at a disadvantage;
- If opponents are hidden from Bob's eyesight or they are snipers outside the half-mile range, Bob is at a big disadvantage;

3. Whether Bob should be locked out - good question. It depends on Bob's own motives and behavior as well as on those of his opponents.
4. *How* Bob can be locked out? The answer seems to be hanging on a condition that Bob should be able to **see** its target. If Bob is kept in darkness, and/or wears non-removable blindfold, or permanently loses his eyesight, he can be kept in jail.

Comment: How fast does a bullet travel? Seems to me Bob can rotate the space between him and the guns so fast the bullets reverse direction and kill the shooters. Or, they exit the cylinder in all directions, scattering everyone. Like dropping ball bearings on a spinning disk. OOOps.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second the bullets can indeed be scattered, but it's very unlikely that any precision can be achieved. Bullets' own spinning would be lost for sure.

Comment: Line of sight isn't sufficient though. Behind one of those very glossy windows there is a guy with a long range gun. Which one? Pick fast.

Answer (score 0):

He could send the bullets back, but with constraints, we can find how fast a projectile has to be traveling in order to not be sent right back. If we go with a 50-ft ring rotating at Mach 1, that means that it takes 141 ms to rotate 360 degrees, so it'll take 70.3 ms to rotate 180 degrees. A bullet will have to be traveling at least 217 m/s to not be sent back at the shooter, if it were to travel the whole distance. If you were going with a bullet that goes straight across, and has a trajectory shift of no more than a single degree, the minimum speed will have to be 39.0 km/s, which is far faster than any bullet that our current technological level can afford.

After all, it depends on what type of gun they're using. He could still rotate the ground to erect a wall that will absorb the bullets, and make his escape, or bury them alive, or cut them in half all at once. Another factor is where exactly Bob's opponents are. If they surround him on all sides, he will be forced to make a risky move that if done wrong will either crush him under the earth, result in him getting shot up, or bisect him. But if they're all grouped together, they'll be easy to deal with all at once. And to take him out, just stab out his eyes and lock him in a regular prison. Or, have snipers with an attack range more than 801 m (.5 mi).